# Print a square root symbol (√) in java

Tags: java, unicode, printing, square-root

I am just wondering how do you print a square root(√) character in Java?
I am assuming you use its unicode or something?

Comment: 1) find the character; 2) copy it into the source code; 3) pray it's present in the font face where it needs to be.

Comment: There is a Unicode square root symbol, "\u221A". In this day and age most, but not all fonts, contain the glyph.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply

```
System.out.println("Square Root: \u221A");
```

Source: [first match on Google](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm).

Comment: Turns out this is now the first match on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the unicode number for it: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm

And this prints it out to a file for me:

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
        FileUtils.write(new File("out.txt"), "\u221A", "UTF8");
    }


}
```

When I open that file, it has the square root symbol in it.

Comment: But what is the code required to turn that into a character?

Answer (score 1):

A question related to this was already asked:

[square root character/symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726799/square-root-character-symbol)

Check out the post and see if this works for you. This site might also have some answers for you:

http://java2everyone.blogspot.com/2009/04/square-root-symbol-in-java.html