# Taking a square root equation and representing it as a string in Java

Tags: java, string, square-root, mathematical-expressions

I'm trying to represent a square root in a string in Java, however ...

The Unicode for a square root, which is \u221A, just prints the symbol for a square root - I want it to wrap around my equation like so:

[An example of a normal square root equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Dfw.gif)

But it comes out like this, as expected:

[The Unicode symbol for a square root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjq9L.jpg)

How can I format my string to represent the square roots as such?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can have a straight `String` that looks like that.  What are you actually trying to achieve?  Are you just trying to draw it on the screen?  Or make a PDF file?  Or something different?

Comment: Actually, in Java String, the square root symbol shows like your second link.   I think this link might helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672161/print-a-square-root-symbol-%E2%88%9A-in-java

Comment: I'm trying to represent a string in an AlertDialog using Android Studio. For a mobile app. Should have clarified.

Comment: OK, if I had to do that, I'd probably just draw three lines directly on the window.  I'd experiment a little bit to get the best looking lengths and angles.

Comment: Does it _have_ to look like it came out of a math textbook?  A Java-like syntax with the square root symbol occupying the place of a method name is (I think) very readable:  `√(3x + 1)`.

Comment: Ok. I'll try those. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want to print this to the console then you cannot achieve what you are attempting to do - the closest you could achieve is an approximation of the overbar using underscores, eg:

```
 ___
√ x
```

If you aren't using the console and instead a rich rendering device (eg a Swing GUI, or a browser window) you may be able to achieve something richer in HTML using MathML (may require further JavaScript library support):

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <msqrt>
        <mrow>x</mrow>
    </msqrt>
</math>
```

or by drawing it yourself into a suitable graphics context, eg a Graphics2D.

Comment: Thanks for that! I should clarify, it's for a mobile app and the string is being represented in an AlertDialog box. And the IDE being used is Android Studio.